# Adjoint operator in sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

Let $g\in H_0^1(\Omega)\cap W^{2,\infty}(\Omega),$ and let us define the operator $B : y \to g y$ from $H:=H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$ to $H$, which we endowed with norm  $|u|=(\|u\|^2 +\|\Delta u\|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the norm of $L^2(\Omega).$

I want to explicit the adjoint operator $B^*$ of $B$ in $(H,|.|)$.

Comment: This seems more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com. But note that it suffices to find the adjoint for compactly smooth functions. 

Comment: Cross-post at MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382602/adjoint-operator-in-sobolev-space

Comment: Yes he is a co-worker 